# AES-256-CTR Encrypting via C# and Decrypting in JS

Tags: c#, encryption, aes, bouncycastle, cryptojs

Using library **Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto** for C# project and **crypto-js** for JS project.

Trying to encrypt data via C# which outputs a string using the function below:

```
public string EncryptData(string data)
{
    byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
    byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ENCRYPTION_KEY);
    IBufferedCipher cipher = CipherUtilities.GetCipher("AES/CTR/NoPadding");
        cipher.Init(true, new ParametersWithIV(ParameterUtilities.CreateKeyParameter("AES", keyBytes), new byte[16]));

    byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.DoFinal(inputBytes);
    string base64EncryptedOutputString = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);

    return base64EncryptedOutputString;
}
```

Then using the function below, in JS, to decrypt:

```
function decrypt(text) {
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, password);
    var dec = decipher.update(text, "hex", "utf8");
    dec += decipher.final("utf8");
    return dec;
}
```

Function to encrypt via JS is below, in case it helps trying to make the C# code the same as the JS code (not the other way around):

```
function encrypt(text) {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, password);
    var crypted = cipher.update(text, "utf8", "hex");
    crypted += cipher.final("hex");
    return crypted;
}
```

The decrypt function seems to be returning an empty string, when it should be returning the original data inputted.

Any ideas what may be the issue here?

Comment: What do you see when you step through `decrypt` with a valid value for `text`? Which line behaves not as you expect?

Comment: decipher and everything below it, variables, are empty. However, algorithm and password and text are populated correctly with the right values. @AakashM